# Crystal Reports ActiveX Viewer

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports, activex, report

When using the Crystal Reports ActiveX viewer (with Delphi XE3 in this case), how do you specify the report file to view ??? There is no property in the CR control in which to enter the name or location of the report.

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal Reports XI ActiveX viewer is not functional.  I guess you're trying to use it to make Crystal Reports work with Delphi. It doesn't. It doesn't even work anywhere else. The latest install of Crystal Reports XI doesn't even ship with the ActiveX version, only the .net version.

There are still installers floating around (or on your local network) that include this ActiveX control but the CR XI forum discussions (Crystal Reports now managed by SAP) point to the ActiveX control being deprecated almost a decade ago, non-functional for the last 5 years, and removed completely from the latest installers, over 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveXViewer *does* work with Delphi XE3. Here's a sample:

```
unit crystalreports;

interface

uses Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,       
Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.OleCtrls,      
ActiveX, ComObj, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB, CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib11_TLB;

type 
TReportForm = class(TForm)
 CrystalReportsViewer: TCrystalActiveXReportViewer; 
 PreviewButton: TButton; 
 procedure PreviewButtonClick(Sender: TObject); 
 private { Private declarations } 
 public { Public declarations } 
 end;

 var ReportForm : TReportForm;

 implementation

 {$R *.dfm}

 procedure TReportForm.PreviewButtonClick(Sender: TObject); 
    var CReport, CRApp : variant; 
    i :integer; 

begin 
CRApp := CreateOleObject('CrystalRuntime.Application'); 
CReport := CRApp.OpenReport('C:\Crystal Reports Test\companydatasheet.rpt',0 ); 
for i := 1 to CReport.Database.Tables.Count do 
begin 
    CReport.Database.Tables[1].ConnectionProperties.Item['User ID'] := 'sa';  
    CReport.Database.Tables[1].ConnectionProperties.Item['Password'] := 'secret'; 
end; 
CReport.RecordSelectionFormula := '{member.member_no} = "101"';        
CrystalReportsViewer.Align := alClient; 
CrystalReportsViewer.ReportSource := CReport; 
ReportForm.WindowState := wsMaximized; 
PreviewButton.Visible := False; 
CrystalReportsViewer.ViewReport; 
CrystalReportsViewer.Show; PreviewButton.Visible := True; 
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can agree with The ActiveXViewer does work with Delphi 10.1.

How to use crystal reports in Delphi?

Get and install the runtime Version XI - "RDC 11.5-Runtime-(11/25/10)" from https://randemsystems.com/crystalreports.html

To include the RDC runtime library into Delphi, start a new project in Delphi and follow these steps:

1. Select the Project menu and then the Import Type Library.
2. In the Import Type Library, Select Crystal Report x ActiveX Designer Runtime Library and rename all the Txxxxxx to TCrxxxxxxxxx
   sample :TApplication and TReport and TDatabase class names to TCrApplication TCrReport and TCrDatabase to avoid the naming conflicts.
3. Click the Install button, click the Into New Package tab, provide a file name path for the new package, and select ok.
4. In the Confirm box, click Yes On Delphi’s ActiveX tab. There is now an Application object icon and TCrReport object icon.
5. From Delphi’s ActiveX tab, place an Application object onto Form1. This adds OleServer and CRAXDRT_TLB to the Uses clause on Form1.
   read more on... https://developerpublish.com/crystal-report-in-delphi-7/

this is a sample app to load crystal report file and view it with Interface or OleObject

```
unit UFormCrystalReports;
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
{$WARN UNIT_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  ActiveX, ComObj, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.OleCtrls, Vcl.OleServer, CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib11_5_TLB, CRAXDRT_TLB;

type
  TFormCrystalReports = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    PreviewButton: TButton;
    CrystalReportsViewer: TCrystalActiveXReportViewer;
    PreviewInterface: TButton;
    OpenFileButton: TButton;
    procedure PreviewButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PreviewInterfaceClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OpenFileButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    _Continue: integer;
    fFileName: string;
    pDllName, pProvider, pServerName, pDatabaseName, pUserID, pPassword: string;
    aRep: IReport;
    procedure ConnectToDatabase;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormCrystalReports: TFormCrystalReports;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormCrystalReports.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fFileName := 'L1_900.rpt';
  Caption := 'Crystal report viewer XI : read file = ' + fFileName;
  UseLatestCommonDialogs := True;
end;

procedure TFormCrystalReports.OpenFileButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  cExportTitle, cExportFilter, cExportExt, cFilename, cDirectory: string;
begin

  cExportFilter := 'Crystal report files |*.rpt';
  cExportExt := 'rpt';
  cExportTitle := 'Select the report file';
  cFilename := 'L1_900.rpt';
  cDirectory := GetCurrentDir();

  if (PromptForFileName(cFilename, cExportFilter, cExportExt, cExportTitle, cDirectory, False)) then
    begin
      if (MessageBox(0, PChar('The selected report file is' + #13#10 +
        PChar(ExtractFileName(cFilename))), PChar('Confirmation'), MB_ICONQUESTION or MB_YESNO or
        MB_TOPMOST or MB_SYSTEMMODAL or MB_DEFBUTTON1) = idYes) then
          if FileExists( cFileName ) then
           begin
             fFileName := cFilename;
              Caption := 'Crystal report viewer XI : read file = ' + fFileName;
              ShowMessage('Run report -> "Preview with Interface" ' + #13#10 +' or "Preview with OleObject" button');
           end
          else
            with TTaskDialog.Create(Self) do
              begin
                try
                  Caption := 'The report file is not exists.';
                  CommonButtons := [tcbOk];
                  DefaultButton := tcbOk;
                  ExpandButtonCaption := 'Additional information';
                  ExpandedText := 'Looking for file : ' + #13#10 + cFilename;
                  Flags := [tfAllowDialogCancellation, tfShowMarqueeProgressBar, tfPositionRelativeToWindow];
                  Title := ExtractFileName(cFilename);
                  Text := 'Sample text';
                  MainIcon := tdiWarning;
                  Execute;
                finally
                  Free;
                end;
              end;
    end;

end;

procedure TFormCrystalReports.PreviewInterfaceClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Cr_App: TCrApplication;
begin
  Cr_App := TCrApplication.Create(Self);
  try
    pDllName := 'crdb_ado.dll';
    pProvider := 'SQLNCLI10.1';
    pServerName := 'your-servername';
    pDatabaseName := '';
    pUserID := 'your-username';
    pPassword := 'your-password';

    _Continue := 0;

    aRep := nil;
    aRep := Cr_App.OpenReport(fFileName, 1);

    ConnectToDatabase;

    if _Continue = 1 then
      begin
        // if (CrystalReportsViewer.ReportSource <> nil) then
        // IReport(CrystalReportsViewer.ReportSource).PrinterSetup(0);
        CrystalReportsViewer.Align := alClient;
        CrystalReportsViewer.ReportSource := aRep;
        CrystalReportsViewer.Visible := True;
        CrystalReportsViewer.Zoom(100);
        CrystalReportsViewer.ViewReport;

      end;

  finally
    Cr_App.free;
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;

end;

procedure TFormCrystalReports.ConnectToDatabase;
var
  i: integer;
  DB: IDatabaseTable;
  s: string;
begin
  try
    for i := 1 to aRep.Database.Tables.Count do
      begin
        DB := aRep.Database.Tables.Item[i];
        try
          s := DB.Location;
          DB.SetLogOnInfo(pServerName, pDatabaseName, pUserID, pPassword);
          DB.Location := s;
        finally
          DB := nil;
        end;
      end;

    if aRep.Get_HasSavedData then
      aRep.DiscardSavedData;

    _Continue := 1;
  except
    _Continue := 0;
  end;

end;

procedure TFormCrystalReports.PreviewButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  CReport, CRApp: variant;
  i: integer;
begin
  CRApp := CreateOleObject('CrystalRuntime.Application');
  CReport := CRApp.OpenReport(fFileName, 0);
  for i := 1 to CReport.Database.Tables.Count do
    begin
      CReport.Database.Tables[1].ConnectionProperties.Item['User ID'] := 'your-username';
      CReport.Database.Tables[1].ConnectionProperties.Item['Password'] := 'your-password';
    end;
  // CReport.RecordSelectionFormula := '{member.member_no} = "101"';
  CrystalReportsViewer.Align := alClient;
  CrystalReportsViewer.ReportSource := CReport;
  PreviewButton.Visible := False;
  CrystalReportsViewer.ViewReport;
  CrystalReportsViewer.Show;
  PreviewButton.Visible := True;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

For Delphi 11.2 Alexandria, it wasn't possible to create crystal report viewer component from type library.
But it is possible to view the report via TOleObject.

```
1.To include the Crystal Report RDC runtime library into Delphi, start a new project in Delphi and follow these steps:
    Select the Project menu and then the Import Type Library.
    In the Import Type Library :
    Search for "Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer"
    Select the "Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer Run Time Library 11.5" 
    Press Import, on Class Name(s) rename all the Txxxxxx to TCrxxxxxxxxx 
    sample :TApplication and TReport and TDatabase class names to TCrApplication TCrReport and TCrDatabase to avoid the naming conflicts.
    Unit Dir Name -> the desired directory on your path or on the project folder. Create Unit. Finish.
2. In Project Options : Building-Delphi Compiler-Linking-> Data Execution Prevention compatible : Set to False !!!!
    ( if not it will crash !!!)
```

this is a sample application to load a crystal report file and view it with TOleObject.

```
unit UFormOLECrystalReportViewer;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, System.UITypes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.OleCtnrs, CRAXDRT_TLB;

type
  TFormOLECrystalReportViewer = class(TForm)
    PanelTop: TPanel;
    OpenFileButton: TButton;
    ViewButton: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ViewButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OpenFileButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    _Continue: Byte;
    fFileName: string;
    pProvider, pServerName, pDatabaseName, pUserID, pPassword: string;
    CrystalReport: IReport;
    procedure InitParams;
    procedure ConnectToDatabase;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormOLECrystalReportViewer: TFormOLECrystalReportViewer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormOLECrystalReportViewer.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fFileName := 'L1_900.rpt';
  Caption := 'Crystal report viewer XI : read file = ' + fFileName;
  ViewButton.Enabled := False;
  UseLatestCommonDialogs := True;
end;

procedure TFormOLECrystalReportViewer.InitParams;
begin
  pProvider := 'SQLNCLI10.1';
  pServerName := 'your-ServerName';
  pDatabaseName := 'your-DatabaseName';
  pUserID := 'your-username';
  pPassword := 'your-password';
end;

procedure TFormOLECrystalReportViewer.OpenFileButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  cExportTitle, cExportFilter, cExportExt, cFilename, cDirectory: string;
begin
  ViewButton.Enabled := False;
  cExportFilter := 'Crystal report files |*.rpt';
  cExportExt := 'rpt';
  cExportTitle := 'Select the report file';
  cFilename := fFileName;
  cDirectory := GetCurrentDir();

  if (PromptForFileName(cFilename, cExportFilter, cExportExt, cExportTitle, cDirectory, False)) then
  begin
    fFileName := cFilename;
    Caption := 'Crystal Report Viewer XI : ' + fFileName;
    ViewButton.Enabled := True;
    ViewButtonClick(Self);
  end;
end;

procedure TFormOLECrystalReportViewer.ConnectToDatabase;
var
  i: integer;
  DB: IDatabaseTable;
  S: string;
begin
  InitParams;
  try
    for i := 1 to CrystalReport.Database.Tables.Count do
    begin
      DB := CrystalReport.Database.Tables.Item[i];
      try
        S := DB.Location;
        DB.SetLogOnInfo(pServerName, pDatabaseName, pUserID, pPassword);
        DB.Location := S;
      finally
        DB := nil;
      end;
    end;
    _Continue := 1;
  except
    _Continue := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormOLECrystalReportViewer.ViewButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  CrystalApp: CRAXDRT_TLB.TCrApplication;
  CrystalOleContainer: TOleContainer;
  frm: TForm;
begin
  CrystalApp := CRAXDRT_TLB.TCrApplication.Create(Self);
  CrystalReport := nil;
  CrystalReport := CrystalApp.OpenReport(fFileName, 0);
  if CrystalReport.Get_HasSavedData then
    CrystalReport.DiscardSavedData;

  CrystalReport.EnableParameterPrompting := True;
  frm := TForm.Create(Self);
  try
    _Continue := 0;
    ConnectToDatabase;
    if (_Continue = 0) then
      ViewButton.Caption := 'Try to open other file...';

    if _Continue = 1 then
    begin
      ViewButton.Caption := 'View Report';
      CrystalOleContainer := TOleContainer.Create(Self);
      with CrystalOleContainer do
      begin
        name := 'CrystalOleContainer';
        Caption := 'CrystalOleContainer';
        Parent := frm; // Self;
        AutoActivate := aaGetFocus;
        AutoVerbMenu := False;
        Align := alClient;
        BorderStyle := bsNone;
        Color := clWindow;
        CopyOnSave := False;
        SizeMode := smAutoSize;
        TabOrder := 1;
      end;

      CrystalOleContainer.CreateObject('CrystalReports.ActiveXReportViewer', False);
      CrystalOleContainer.OleObject.EnableExportButton := True;
      CrystalOleContainer.OleObject.EnableCloseButton := True;
      CrystalOleContainer.OleObject.EnableAnimationCtrl := True;
      CrystalOleContainer.OleObject.DisplayGroupTree := True;
      CrystalOleContainer.OleObject.DisplayTabs := True;
      CrystalOleContainer.OleObject.DisplayBorder := True;
      CrystalOleContainer.OleObject.ReportSource := CrystalReport;
     // CrystalOleContainer.SetFocus;
      frm.Left := FormOLECrystalReportViewer.Left;
      frm.Width := FormOLECrystalReportViewer.Width;
      frm.Top := FormOLECrystalReportViewer.Top;
      frm.Height := FormOLECrystalReportViewer.Height;
      frm.Caption := FormOLECrystalReportViewer.Caption;

      frm.Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
      frm.ShowModal;
    end;

  finally
    FreeAndNil(frm);
    FreeAndNil(CrystalApp);
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Comment: Why have you posted two separate answers to the same question? Can they be merged into one?

Comment: Sorry about. Yes they be merged